# Scrolling Background Animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

This is my code:

```
<DrawingBrush Viewport="0,0,16,16" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile" x:Key="dbCheckerBoard">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="LightGray">
                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,8,8"/>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="8,8,8,8"/>
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="White">
                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="8,0,8,8"/>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,8,8,8"/>
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

which gives my control element the following background:

[image]

Now I want to gently scroll the background so that it looks animated, can anyone tell me how do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried animating the `ViewPort` x/y properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding:

```
<ControlName.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ControlName.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <RectAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Viewport"
                    From="0 0 16 16" To="16 16 16 16" Duration="0:0:1"
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</ControlName.Triggers>
```

To the control of `ControlName` that the drawing brush is used on (assuming it's used as the `Background`).

If you wanted to make this a bit more automatic you could try creating a style that combines the two:

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollingGridStyle" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DrawingBrush
                ... Grid background brush
                ...
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <RectAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Viewport"
                        From="0 0 16 16" To="16 16 16 16" Duration="0:0:1"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And then use it like:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ScrollingGridStyle}"/>
```

Or, add it to your existing styles like:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" 
       x:Key="MyPrettyTextBox" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollingGridStyle}">
```

Unfortunately, WPF doesn't have very much support for creating composite styles.

Comment: Edited - you can only use triggers on controls.

Comment: Thanks, its works perfect, but is there a way to add the animation to the DrawingBrush so that whatever control I use the DrawingBrush on, it will automatically scroll?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I've edited my answer to include a slightly nicer alternative you could use.